# How to connect secure websocket by using Poco in C++

Tags: c++, wss, poco-libraries

I am trying to use secure websocket by using C++ to connect echo.websocket.org. It works in javascript at https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

My solution is to use Poco libraries and my code looks like following.

```
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();

Poco::Net::Context context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");

Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession Client("echo.websocket.org", 443, &context);
//SSL Exception on above line

Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/?encoding=text", Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
request.set("origin", "https://www.websocket.org");
Poco::Net::HTTPResponse response;

try
{
    Poco::Net::WebSocket webSocket(Client, request, response);

    std::string str = "Hello!";

    char receiveBuff[256];

    int len = webSocket.sendFrame(str.data(), str.size(), Poco::Net::WebSocket::FRAME_TEXT);
    std::cout << "Sent bytes " << len << std::endl;
    int flags = 0;

    int rlen = webSocket.receiveFrame(receiveBuff, 256, flags);
    std::cout << "Received bytes " << rlen << std::endl;
    std::cout << receiveBuff << std::endl;

    webSocket.close();
}
catch (std::exception &e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception " << e.what();
}
```

But I get SSL Exception with this code. Can anybody help me, please? Thanks

Comment: Why not, like, provide some more information about the "SSL Exception". Not that I have expertise in that particular area, but I can recognize a question of the type "My car key doesn't work" when I see it. Like, is it the right car, for instance?

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.
Anyway, I found a solution. It's a testsuite in https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/develop/NetSSL_OpenSSL/testsuite
But another problem is that I can't figured it out how it works.
For example, I think pem file is used for certification, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In the testsuite, it's the [test driver](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/NetSSL_OpenSSL/testsuite/src/Driver.cpp#L55) that does it for you, from the [configuration file](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/NetSSL_OpenSSL/testsuite/TestSuite.xml#L4-L5).

As for how to do it by hand, it would be like this:

```
class MyInvalidCertificateHandler: public InvalidCertificateHandler
{
public:
    MyInvalidCertificateHandler(bool handleOnServerSide):
        InvalidCertificateHandler(handleOnServerSide) { }

    virtual ~MyInvalidCertificateHandler() { }

    void onInvalidCertificate(const void*, VerificationErrorArgs& errorCert)
    {
        //log or something
        errorCert.setIgnoreError(false);
    }
};

std::string certFilename = "my/cert/filename"; // path to file
SharedPtr<InvalidCertificateHandler> ptrCert = new MyInvalidCertificateHandler(false);
Context::Ptr ptrContext = new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", certFilename, VERIFY_STRICT, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(0, ptrCert, ptrContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your clarification.
Anyway, I found a solution. 
It's a testsuite. And you can fine here - https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/develop/NetSSL_OpenSSL/testsuite
But another problem is that I can't figured it out how it works.
For example, I think pem file is used for certification, but I don't know how to do it.